# How can I pull data from a .sqlite file into Databricks Spark?

Tags: sqlite, databricks, kaggle

I found a dataset I like on Kaggle however the only download option is a .sqlite file that has the three tables. Is there anyway I can access this data from Databricks?

Comment: sqlite -> CSV -> Databricks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pyspark and SQLContext, try the following code.

Add extraClassPath to your spark conf.
spark.executor.extraClassPath=<jdbc.jar>

Code snippet:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlCtx = SQLContext(sc)

sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(
    url="jdbc:sqlite:{folder_path}/{file_name}.db",
    driver="org.sqlite.JDBC",
    dbtable="employee")
    .load().take(10)
```